# Static variable not updating after redirect

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

First Form2 wants to update Class file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
           Class1.AddButton = 1;
           Class1.ChiefAnswer = "Done";
        }
```

Class File, form 1 retrieve from class file, meaning i have to just update the class file and when it redirect from form2 to form1 , it will reload

```
private static int AddBtn = 0;
public static int AddButton
        {
            get { return AddBtn; }
            set { AddBtn = value; }
        }
```

Form1(Not updated, the class seems to still hold a older value)

```
 if (Class1.AddButton == 3)
 {
     MakeButton();
 }
```

At fist everyone was working fine after i started to add more variables and fixing the list in my form 2, it didnt work which didnt make sense. When i debugged it , in form 2 , it shows that the AddButton = 3 inside form 2

While debugging is going on , i switch to class1.cs , the value isnt updated(may its not real time)

Anyway , by the time it reaches form1 which retrieves from class1.cs, its not retrieving the value i'm expecting

Thanks for you help! :)

Comment: Why aren't you just using a querystring? What you have now won't support tombstoning (and you're only storing an int)- but using a Querystring will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

querystring method

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PanoramaPage1.xaml?selected=item2", UriKind.Relative));

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected = String.Empty;

        //check to see if the selected parameter was passed.
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("selected"))
        {
            //get the selected parameter off the query string from MainPage.
            selected = NavigationContext.QueryString["selected"];
        }

        //did the querystring indicate we should go to item2 instead of item1?
        if (selected == "item2")
        {
            //item2 is the second item, but 0 indexed. 
            myPanorama.DefaultItem = myPanorama.Items[1];
        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try switching the order of those statements, so do the update before the redirect:

```
Class1.AddButton = 1;
Class1.ChiefAnswer = "Done";
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```